# Для чего комбинируют эти команды git fetch , git reset --hard origin/master?

Tags: git

Есть много примеров где используются команды

```
 git fetch
 git reset --hard origin/master
```

Для чего комбинируют эти команды ?

Если есть ссылки буду рад посмотреть.

Comment: `git reset` устанавливает `HEAD` в указанное состояние. Атрибут `--hard` используется в тех случаях, когда нужно проигнорировать внесённые изменения. Все есть в документации. Так что смысл такой: подтянули с сервера изменения, наплевали на все локальные правки и установили HEAD в актуальное для origin/master состояние

Comment: Когда хотят **гарантировать** неотличимость локальной копии от оригинального репозитория. В общем случае (если вы реально ведёте разработку в этом проекте) так делать **не рекомендуется**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git fetch` притягивает все ветки из внешнего репозитория. Внешний репо еще называют `upstream` и чаще всего проекция на апстрим называется `origin`. Заметьте, хоть локальная ветка `master` и повторяет апстрим ветку `origin/master`, это не одно и то же. `git fetch` не обновляет локальный `master`, она обновляет только `origin/*` ветки, в том числе и `origin/master`. Обновление текущей ветки в основном делается при помощи `git pull`. Хозяйке на заметку:

`git pull` в мастере равносилен (почти)

```
git fetch
git merge origin/master
```

Далее по `git reset --hard origin/master`. Пока вы не сделали `git push`, все ваши коммиты сидят в ветке `master`. А `origin/master` по прежнему чиста от последних незапушенных изменений. Поэтому команда `git reset --hard origin/master` говорит гиту `приведи пожалуйста файловую структуру и историю коммитов моей ветки к тому состоянию, в котором сейчас находится ветка origin/master`.

Comment: Для чего эти команды комбинируют,  в чем смысл использования этих команд один после другого ?

Comment: их не обязательно комбинировать. Но если вам хочется чтоб мастер заресетился с самыми последними измнениями с сервера, то прийдётся сделать `git fetch`.